# Can't move a view to the center of the screen (programmatically, not with layout properties) - Android

Tags: android, image

This might look like a very common problem but I can't seem to move a view to the center of the screen.

I have 3 views:

- a background image (center crop)
- a black/white grid to visualize the center of the screen, for debugging purpose. Also center crop
- a square that I want to move to the center, top left corner of the square at the center of the screen.

I first get the screen size in pixels, divide width and height by 2 to get the coordinates of the center. Then move my square view by center.x and center.y
I expect the square to be moves precisely to the center of the screen.

I also scale the square view so its size is always the same relative to the background image.

I want to solve this programmatically (not just centering with layout properties) because it is only a first step, I intend to be able to place the square anywhere I want on the screen. I try to place in the center here because it seems like the easiest thing to do.

**The code**

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
    }

}
```

**The class whit the logic**

```
public class AnimalPopupActivity extends FullScreenActivity {

    private final String TAG = "AnimalPopup";

    ImageView backgroundView;
    ImageView square;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal_popup);

        backgroundView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background);

        square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.square);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int screenWidthInPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeightInPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
        Log.i(TAG, "screen width pixels: "+screenWidthInPixels);
        Log.i(TAG, "screen height pixels: "+screenHeightInPixels);

        Point center = new Point(screenWidthInPixels/2, screenHeightInPixels/2);
        Log.i(TAG, "center: "+center);

        double ratioH = (double)screenWidthInPixels/100d;
        Log.i(TAG, "ratioH: "+ratioH);
        double ratioV = (double)screenHeightInPixels/100d;
        Log.i(TAG, "ratioV: "+ratioV);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(10*ratioH), (int)(10*ratioV));
        layoutParams.leftMargin = center.x;
        layoutParams.topMargin = center.y;
        square.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bentaye.app.games.AnimalPopupActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/animal_popup_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/animal_popup_grid" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/square" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is what I get on a Nexus 5** (1080*1920:420dpi)
[image: Nexus5]

With the following logs:

> screen width pixels: 1080
>
> screen height pixels: 1794
>
> center: Point(540, 897)
>
> ratioH: 10.8
>
> ratioV: 17.94

**Here is what I get on a Nexus 10** (2560*1600:xhdpi)
[image: Nexus 10]

With the following logs:

> screen width pixels: 1600
>
> screen height pixels: 2464
>
> center: Point(800, 1232)
>
> ratioH: 16.0
>
> ratioV: 24.64

The 2 are off by a few pixels, I am not an Android specialist and clearly I am doing something wrong but can't understand what.

Any help welcome. Cheers!

**EDIT:** I think that it is due the calculation taking the status bar into account. It also explains why the discrepancy is bigger on the Nexus5, as the status bar is bigger relatively to the screen height. And also why the discrepancy only affects the vertical alignment.
I'll come back and post the code once I sort it out.

Comment: Why was my last edit with my solution removed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the square you want centered is inside the RelativeLayout, add `layout_gravity=center`

For example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity=center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/square"/>
```

Comment: As said in the question, I want to solve this programmatically (not just centering with layout properties) because it is only a first step, I intend to be able to place the square anywhere I want on the screen. I try to place in the center here because it seems like the easiest thing to do.

Comment: layout_gravity=center is not work for RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Add this Line

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

this line is for RelativeLayout